# Scanning WiFi Networks

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am trying to create a button for each WiFi network. I am using the following code:

```
public void RefreshWifi(View v)
{
    try {
        wifi.startScan();
        wifinetworks = wifi.getScanResults();
        Toast.makeText(this, wifinetworks.toString(), 1).show();
        if (wifinetworks != null) {
            for (ScanResult i : wifinetworks) {
                Button newbutton = new Button(this);
                newbutton.setText(i.getClass().getName());

                wifilayout.addView(newbutton);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + e.toString(), 1).show();
    }
}
```

However I keep getting 'toasted' with `java.lang.nullpointerexceptions`.

It doesn't even toast the first toast statement. `wifi` is a `WifiManager` and `wifinetworks` is a `List<ScanResult>`. Thank you.

Update: Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.fireoak.hacker.MainActivity.RefreshWifi(MainActivity.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT: I AM AN IDIOT. forgot to set `wifi` to actual WifiManager...

Comment: How do I do that? I'm using AIDE on Nexus 7 FYI.

Comment: have you used all the required permission in manifest...

Comment: I don't know what AIDE is. Look on the logcat, there's the detailed exception.

Comment: @akashgupta No :-) any links I could use to do that?

Comment: Btw, [do NOT catch Exception](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/12/04/exceptions.html)

Comment: @m0skit0 AIDE is an Android app that lets you make android apps on your android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `wifinetworks` before the null check:

```
    Toast.makeText(this, wifinetworks.toString(), 1).show();
    if (wifinetworks != null) {
```

If `wifinetworks` is null on the Toast, then you obviously get an NPE at `wifinetworks.toString()`

Comment: I commented out first toast...still the same.

Comment: What "still the same"? Same exception? How can you know? Again, post the stack trace.

Comment: My second toast comes up with the error.trying othernanswernwill update if works.

Comment: Wow dude... That means nothing, that's only the exception **message**. That's not the **stack trace**. You should start with Java basics before trying to program Android.

Comment: Your stack trace misses line numbers at `com.fireoak.hacker.MainActivity.RefreshWifi(MainActivity.java)`. Which line is this one in your code?

Comment: What do you mean missing line numbers? That routine is posted in original post. Sorry for noob questions, I am a VB developer just doing android as hobby, just started :-) .

Answer (score 1):

use them in android manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```